# Why doesn't my c# code recognize copyright symbol?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

```
byte[] newBytes = new Byte[] { 169 };
string string1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
```

In the above program, I expected string1 to have the value of copyright symbol ©.

But I get some other value (possibly some junk) as shown below

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644785/is-it-possible-to-get-a-copyright-symbol-in-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: Wrong encoding, that isn't utf-8.  Encoding.Default or Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) have odds of working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) requires multiple bytes to encode character points greater than 127. If you run the reverse, you'll see what it expects:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("©"); // { 194, 169 }
```

Try this:

```
byte[] newBytes = new Byte[] { 194, 169 };
string string1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
```

If you absolutely *have* to use that original byte array, you'll need to pick a different encoding. For example, the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding uses a single byte to encode the copyright symbol:

```
byte[] newBytes = new Byte[] { 169 };
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
string string1 = encoding.GetString(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length); // "©"
```