# Symbol in added Watermark isn't correctly shown in C# Word Interop

Tags: c#, word-interop

My program has a function to add a watermark to word files, but a symbol 'Ⓒ' is not shown correctly, just a square like the attached file.(it's rotated).

[image]

I guess I have to write a line of code to use these symbols, but I cannot find it. Can anybody help me?

```
if (file.Watermark == true)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShape = null;
                        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
                        {
                            wordShape = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddTextEffect(
                                             Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
                                             "Ⓒ gg", "Arial", (float)30,
                                             Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                                             Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                             150, 150, ref o);
                            wordShape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                            wordShape.Fill.Solid();
                            wordShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray15;
                            wordShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                            wordShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                            wordShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                            wordShape.Left = 20;
                            wordShape.Top = 250;
                            wordShape.Rotation = -45;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do something like this :**

```
if (file.Watermark == true)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShape = null;
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
                    {
                        wordShape = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddTextEffect(
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
                                         "\u00a9 gg", "Arial", (float)30,
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                         150, 150, ref o);
                        wordShape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                        wordShape.Fill.Solid();
                        wordShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray15;
                        wordShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                        wordShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                        wordShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                        wordShape.Left = 20;
                        wordShape.Top = 250;
                        wordShape.Rotation = -45;
                    }
                }
```

you can replace your symbol by this expression :
**\u00a9**

i thing i will help you

for more informations have a look at this
:

[How to use caracter encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding)

[A similar question has been aked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644785/is-it-possible-to-get-a-copyright-symbol-in-c-sharp-console-application)